# What difference from tns update package vs npm update package

Tags: nativescript

I do not know what difference from `tns update package` vs `npm update package`.
If I update the packages all make well fine.

Comment: using `tns update` will often not work and break the node modules and such. always use `npm update`, or do it manually

Answer (score 0):

`npm update` will simply update all the top level dependencies to latest, in other hand `tns update` will update your run time versions which will not be listed as part of your dependencies, it will also update core modules to it's runtime compatible version.